# Unable to delete file location using remove-item because it does not exist

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script to be implemented in my desk to delete some files for Skype for Business.
I can get the `Get-ChildItem` command to find the folder but when I use the remove item it says that the file does not exist.

The code is

```
$SkypeFile = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\users\env:username\AppData\Local\Microsoft sip_* -Force -Recurse -Directory

Remove-Item $SkypeFile
```

The error code is:

> Remove-item : Cannot find path "c:\New Folder..." *(the file location I getfrom Get-ChildItem)* because it doest not exist.

From what I understand it is searching in the folder that I have the script in and that why it is now working but I am unsure and stuck on why is it doing that.

**EDIT:**

I have managed to find out why was it looking in the script file location, I added the path but now I encountered a problem.

The file I am looking for can be in one of 3 folders titled 14.0 or 15.0 or 13.0 and I cannot make the remove file item look for it in those folders it just tries to look inside the folder.

Comment: Please double-check the code you've pasted. It is highly unlikely that `c:\users\env:username\AppData` is valid a path. The colon character has special meaning and out-of-the-box `env:username` is neither a variable nor a psdrive provider.

Comment: I have resolved it.
I have removed the path completly from remove item and replaced it with 
remove-item $skypefile.fullname
The commend was not being recognized but it worked and deletes the folders.
Thanks for the helpd :D

Comment: @PiotrGruszczyński Please post an answer with the details of the problem cause + solution (so that you can accept it and this can be marked as answered) or delete the question.