# Cannot remove .sonarqube folder on a Windows agent in a DevOps Server pipeline due to a strangely behaving file

Tags: powershell, sonarqube, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server

In our pipelines building .NET apps, we use SonarScanner for Azure DevOps version 4.23.1, using the MSBuild integration. Sometimes, the tasks leave some mess in the .sonarqube directory inside the pipeline's workspace. We use a PowerShell script to delete the folder. Today, it started failing on an agent in a very strange way. It seems the directory's removal is blocked by a file that cannot <strike>even be listed</strike> be deleted, moved, nor opened. It happens only on the specific agent, but it is 100% reproducible.

The script:

```
[string]$sqPath = "$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\.sonarqube\"
Write-Host $sqPath
if (Test-Path -Path $sqPath) {
    Write-Host "Path exists!"
    #Get-ChildItem $sqPath -Recurse -Force  # DEBUG
    Remove-Item $sqPath -Recurse -Force
} else {
    Write-Host "Path doesn't exist."
}
```

The output:

```console
F:\Agents\01-V2\_work\104\.sonarqube\
Path exists!
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item F:\Agents\01-V2\_work\104\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\mod37\ucfg2\js\F__Agents_01_V2__work_1
04_s_Cmpny_Prod_Plugins_SitePrototypes_Cmpny_Prod_Plugins_SitePrototypes_Importer_Modules_ModelCharacterGallery_carouse
l_init_js_62_9_FD_45_tryToGetLargeYoutubeThumbnail.ucfg: Could not find a part of the path 'F__Agents_01_V2__work_104_s
_Cmpny_Prod_Plugins_SitePrototypes_Cmpny_Prod_Plugins_SitePrototypes_Importer_Modules_ModelCharacterGallery_carousel_in
it_js_62_9_FD_45_tryToGetLargeYoutubeThumbnail.ucfg'.
At F:\Agents\01-V2\_work\_temp\eac8036c-a258-4f5e-b3c0-16ce3b6a00d9.ps1:9 char:5
+     Remove-Item $sqPath -Recurse -Force
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (F__Agents_01_V2...eThumbnail.ucfg:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], DirectoryNotFoun 
   dException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

When I uncomment the Get-ChildItem line, the file mentioned by the error message <strike>is not listed anywhere</strike><sup>I added `-Force` and it appeared.</sup> is among the listed files, in a hidden directory, yet the Remove-Item line still fails with the same error.

The agents are custom Azure VMs running Windows, managed by the infrastructure department of our company. We have little info on what is going on there and we can use them just through the pipelines. When we send a ticket to the infrastructure admins, it takes ages to get any response and much time is wasted.

**Is there a way I can diagnose the issue through the pipeline script?** I tried different ways of finding the process that holds the handle to the file but all failed. Most strangely, I found that, unlike *nix systems, Windows does not allow the deletion of a file that is open by a process. So is this an issue with rights? <strike>Why is Get-ChildItem silent about the file when Remove-Item fails during its deletion?</strike> Why does any operation with the file fail? Historically, we had issues with too-long paths, but this time, it seems there is no PathTooLongException.

Comment: Hmmm... I found this might be related. :-( https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8211

Comment: Use `-Force` on your GCI to get all files including hidden ones, or add `-hidden` to get *just* the hidden files - see docs for GCI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: @MisterSmith, thank you! I missed this nuance of Get-ChildItem. I would be very surprised if the file had the hidden flag on, but one never knows.

Comment: I found that F:\Agents\01-V2\_work\104\.sonarqube\out\.sonar is hidden and that the file inside that blocks the deletion has `LastWriteTime : 6/10/2022 3:14:28 PM`. That is strange...

Comment: When creating a draft pipeline, the workspace ID changes. I.e. the 104 in the original path becomes e.g. 246. That makes replicating the issue even more problematic. I can set demands and enable diagnostics per run of the original pipeline, but it takes some clicking in the UI. :-(

Comment: Now I come to think that the issue never went away, I just made a mistake while testing it and I did not notice the workspace ID change for the draft pipeline. :-( Creating a draft pipeline was the easiest way to make the job always run on the same agent. Now when I specify the agent manually when executing the original pipeline, it always fails.

Comment: Note to self: the agent is Agent-SKDACLSADOBW01-01-V2.

Comment: This might be the same issue, but it also might not. And the OP is likely gone. https://stackoverflow.com/q/44279578/2157640

Comment: This is very interesting, but unrelated. I do not use UNC paths and the Delete() method does not work either. https://stackoverflow.com/q/25606481/2157640 The Delete() method fails with `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'F__Agents_01_V2__work_104_s...`.

Comment: The DirectoryNotFoundException puzzles me. `$_.Directory.Exists` is true, but `$_.Delete()` fails with the exception.

Comment: To eliminate PowerShell's obscure behaviors and bugs from the equation, I tried even cmd.exe and its `rd /s /q F:\Agents\01-V2\_work\104\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\mod37\ucfg2\js\ `. It prints the full path to each file in the folder, one per line, each suffixed with `- The system cannot find the path specified.`. 

Comment: BTW, I realized I can use an experimental pipeline separate from the original pipeline. I just need to hardcode the path to the "104" workspace there and add demand for the specific agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages are misleading, likely because an old PowerShell is used (v1.0, according to the path ).

SonarQube somehow managed to create files whose path is [longer than MAX_PATH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd). MAX_PATH is 260 and it includes the trailing NUL character (string terminator). Your path has a length of 261, in this sense, which is just over the limit.

To delete the directory, use this pipeline:

```yaml
pool:
  name: Build
  demands: Agent.Name -equals Agent-SKDACLSADOBW01-01-V2

variables:
  sq: \\?\F:\Agents\01-V2\_work\104\.sonarqube\

steps:
  - checkout: none
  - script: rd /s /q $(sq)
```

It executes the [`rd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rd) (a.k.a. `rmdir`) command in recursive (`/s`), quiet (`/q`) mode on the folder using cmd.exe. This evades many of the idiosyncrasies and bugs of PowerShell. If you need to execute it from within PowerShell, use `&cmd.exe /c rd /s /q $(sq)`. The path needs to be specified as an extended-length path using the `\\?\` prefix. Note that when the prefix is used, forward slashes are not converted to backslashes automatically anymore.

In my case, the one-time cleanup described above did not help as the pipeline still produces the files. I modified the script from the question so that it does not have to be modified to run diagnostics and so that it logs a warning and tags the build `sonarqube-cleanup` each time the cleanup logic is actually used. Based on the tag, I will later be able to find whether the cleanup logic still needs to be there.

```
if ($env:SYSTEM_DEBUG -eq 'true') {
    Write-Host "##[debug]Processes on the agent:"
    Get-Process
}
[string]$sqPath = "$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\.sonarqube\"
if (Test-Path -Path $sqPath) {
    Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=warning]SonarQube folder exists! $sqPath"
    Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]sonarqube-cleanup"
    if ($env:SYSTEM_DEBUG -eq 'true') {
        Write-Host "##[debug]Contents of the SonarQube folder:"
        Get-ChildItem $sqPath -Recurse -Force
    }
    #Remove-Item $sqPath -Recurse -Force
    &cmd.exe /c rd /s /q "\\?\$sqPath"
} else {
    Write-Host "SonarQube folder does not exist. $sqPath"
}
```

---

I found an interesting [GitHub issue about PowerShell support for extended-length paths](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10805).

There are many Q & A on Stack Overflow and Super User that detail how files or folders with long paths can be deleted:

- [Delete directory regardless of 260 char limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16392765/2157640)
- https://superuser.com/q/78434/269404

Answer (score 1):

I *suspect* that this issue is/was being caused by Windows [Maximum Path Length limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd)

As detailed in that article:

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following order: drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by backslashes, and a terminating null character.

If my counting ability is correct, I see that path length is 265 characters, just above the 260 character limit for a path.

Part of the path looks to me to be randomly generated, so could explain why the issue is not occurring all the time.

When running recent versions of Windows, it's possible to enable NTFS Long Path support which will allow this limit to be bypassed by some applications (namely those that have been built with long path awareness - as far as I can tell PowerShell is one such application)

If you'd like to enable NTFS Long Paths, there's an article you can find [here](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/filr/filr-4/filr-desktop/t47bx2ogpfz7.html) that details the process, and just in case the link gets downed at any point, the key steps are:

> 1. Click Windows key and type gpedit.msc, then press the Enter key. This
>    launches the Local Group Policy Editor.
> 2. Navigate to Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration >
>    Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem.
> 3. Double click Enable NTFS long paths.
> 4. Select Enabled, then click OK.

Comment: I used JS in the browser console to get the length of the path and it tells me that it is 260. But yes, I know it is just around the limit. As I wrote in the question, there is no PathTooLongException, so it seemed that this is not the issue this time.

Comment: I see no random parts in the file's path. 01-V2 is the local name of the agent -- there is also 02-V2 on the same machine. 104 is some kind of ID of the pipeline's workspace. The same pipeline running on the same agent always gets the same workspace ID. mod37\ucfg2 seems to be something specific to SonarQube; it is fixed. 62_9_FD_45 is likely some identification of the position of the warning in the corresponding source code file; something like line and column number. Do not have the details now, but it certainly is not random.

Comment: As far as NTFS Long Paths are concerned, I have no power over their support on the target machine as the DevOps agent is managed by a different department of our company. I may try a request, but I am not sure what the reaction will be and whether all the tooling that works with the file will be able to use it -- namely SonarQube and its DevOps task.

Comment: Fair enough, it would seem that my assumptions were indeed incorrect then. I've noted from your debugging attempt, you tried listing the files using `Get-ChildItem $sqPath -Recurse`, if this happens again it would be worth adding the `-Force` parameter to it so that Hidden and System files are also included in the results. Additionally it's worth checking out the $Error variable at the time of the failure to see if you can dig further down into the InnerException(s) and see what's happening.

Comment: You were right after all! It just took more digging into how to handle files with long paths. See the answer I posted. Hope it will help others running into a similar issue.